# Clickable hyperlink of an SVG element

Tags: svg, hyperlink, href, xlink

I'm trying to make a complex SVG path clickable. Using xlink:href works, but only the lines of the path are clickable. To solve this, I drew an invisible rectangle around the path. But the rectangle isn't clickable; only the path lines remain clickable, just like before. The rectangle is definitely there, as judged from the element inspector. What am I doing wrong?

```
<a xlink:href="index.html" target="_top">

<rect
x="160.42851"
y="85.227654"
height="400"
width="400"
style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
id="rect59"/>

<path
id="path3520"
d="m.../>

</a>
```

Comment: set pointer-events="all" on the path or the rect You may not need the rect at all if you do that.

Comment: This worked when done on the rect. Thanks! My path simply has no "fill" (it's a circle with a thick line and nothing in the middle), I've realized. But regarding the rect: isn't the default that it's clickable? Is it always necessary to state pointer-events?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty